# React Backend -> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I understand a similar question has been asked but nothing has helped.
Node.js version: v14.16.1

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
  <h1> MYSQL - NODE - EXPRESS- WEBTOKEN </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });
```

Error:

```
*****@****-MBP backend % npm run start

> *********backend@1.0.0 start /Users/*******/Documents/GitHub/********/backend
> nodemon --exec babel-node index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js`
file:///Users/*******/Documents/GitHub/*******/backend/index.js:2
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
               ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///Users/******/Documents/GitHub/*********/backend/index.js:2:16
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It looks from your error that your file is being loaded as an ES6 module - not CommonJS. Do you have a "type": "module" setup in your package.json file?

Comment: @IAmDranged Yes, I do have "type": "module" in the package.json file

Comment: Ok, try to remove it then. This setup instructs node to load your files as ES6 modules.

Comment: You're a legend!!! I saw this type of question everywhere but no one said to do that.